# how to replace the backslash in php to xml?

Tags: php, backslash

I'm trying to create a xml file from php.... it is not work properly... when i eentered \notepad\text ,it creates in xml file as 
otepad    ext....

what's the solution for this problem? can i use any function to this?

Answer (score 3):

When you write it this way:

```
echo "\notepad\text";
```

`\n` will be interpreted as a newline and `\t` as a tab.

Try single quotes:

```
echo '\notepad\text';
```

or escape the backslash characters:

```
echo "\\notepad\\text";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace them with the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

Or just use forward slashes and

```
$string = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $string);
```

To make using this constant less cumbersome, you can do this

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Joomla does this.

If you want to skip the constant all together, you can probably also add an extra backslash to escape the escape character.

As for using a function, you can wrap that `str_replace()` above in a function.